# Elasticsearch highlighted terms vary

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running an Elasticsearch wildcard query with highlighting and wondering why there are extra words highlighted in the results.

A search for `*exampleweb*` shows that the highlighted terms vary (`exampleweb.com`, `beta.exampleweb.com`, etc) when I want only `exampleweb` to be highlighted.

Names is defined as `text` in the mapping if that matters.

**URL**

`http://localhost:9200/wm/_search?filter_path=hits.hits.highlight`

**Request Body**

```
{
   "query":{
      "wildcard":{
         "names":{
            "value":"*exampleweb*"
         }
      }
   },
   "highlight":{
      "fields":{
         "names":{}
      }
   }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "highlight": {
                    "names": [
                        "325-<em>beta.exampleweb.com</em>"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "highlight": {
                    "names": [
                        "325.<em>exampleweb.com</em>"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "highlight": {
                    "names": [
                        "a2-gt-api-<em>preprod.fr.aws.exampleweb.com</em>"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default standard analyzer is used on the `text` type field. The token generated for `beta.exampleweb.com` will be `beta.exampleweb.com`. Now when you are using wildcard query on `names` the terms matching a wildcard pattern (`*exampleweb*`) i.e `beta.exampleweb.com` will be returned.

**To just highlight `exampleweb` in the names field you need to use [pattern tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html), which will split the text into tokens when `.` is encountered.**

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "\\.| "
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "names": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "names" : "a2-gt-api-preprod.fr.aws.exampleweb.com"
}
{
  "names" : "beta.exampleweb.com"
}
{
  "names" : "325.exampleweb.com"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "names": "exampleweb"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "names": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
{
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "highlight": {
          "names": [
            "beta.<em>exampleweb</em>.com"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "highlight": {
          "names": [
            "325.<em>exampleweb</em>.com"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "highlight": {
          "names": [
            "a2-gt-api-preprod.fr.aws.<em>exampleweb</em>.com"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Using this tokenizer, if I search for leweb, what would exampleweb be highlighted still or leweb?